# Host Image and get it as a link

Tags: postgresql, image, cloud, hosting

I have an application built with react.js, node.js, PostgreSQL. I want to host a bunch of images somewhere and store their links in my database. To frontend will retrieve these images and display them.
I tried [Icedrive](https://icedrive.net/dashboard/#/cloud) eg:[hosted image](https://icedrive.net/0/36lWPFL6FF) and google photos but the link which they provide has some interface and cannot be directly displayed in a  tag.
What free service I can use?

Answer (score 0):

One can use Imgur. As they provide a direct link option that can be used in a  tag.